# PHP: Apply exchange rate from a different table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a cost panel for a financial system.  We have costs in 4 currencies:

PLN (polish zloty), USD,EUR and GBP.
The table *fin_costs* stores all the costs records.

[image]

There is a second table called *fin_exchange_rates* that stores the exchange rates for each month for those currencies. Those values are entered manually by the user.

[image]

The exchange rate must to be multiplied for the values in the column *amount_in_currency* and put the result value in the columns *gross_amount* and *net_amount* (the same value). These columns from the table *fin_costs*

This is what I have so far (for the date february 2013):

```
SELECT currency, amount_in_currency, EUR, USD, GBP,
CASE 
WHEN currency = 'EUR' THEN amount_in_currency * EUR
WHEN currency = 'USD' THEN amount_in_currency * USD
WHEN currency = 'GBP' THEN amount_in_currency * GBP
END AS new_value FROM fin_costs, fin_exchange_rates WHERE year_for_exchange = "2013" AND month_for_exchange = "2" AND year_analysis = "2013" AND month = "2"
```

Where *new_value* is the amount with the exchange rate applied.

Q: How can I update the new value for each row?

Any help will be really appreciated because I'm stuck on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Exchange Rate tables should look something like this   ---- http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/currencies/cross-rates/   --- your fx table i believe is wrong as you have 3 columns relating to which exhange rate per curreny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work for your current table structure. However, I strongly suggest that you consider having one row per currency conversion in your `fin_exchange_rates` table. That way you could simply join on the appropriate row, instead of having all of the `CASE` statements.

Also, this solution assumes that the rates in your `fin_exhange_rates` table are relative to the PLN currency.

```
UPDATE fin_costs fc
    JOIN fin_exchange_rates fer ON fc.year_analysis = fer.year_for_exchange
        AND fc.month = fer.month_for_exchange
SET fc.gross_amount = (CASE 
    WHEN fc.currency = 'EUR' THEN fc.amount_in_currency * fer.EUR
    WHEN fc.currency = 'USD' THEN fc.amount_in_currency * fer.USD
    WHEN fc.currency = 'GBP' THEN fc.amount_in_currency * fer.GBP
    WHEN fc.currency = 'PLN' THEN fc.amount_in_currency
    END),
fc.net_amount = (CASE 
    WHEN fc.currency = 'EUR' THEN fc.amount_in_currency * fer.EUR
    WHEN fc.currency = 'USD' THEN fc.amount_in_currency * fer.USD
    WHEN fc.currency = 'GBP' THEN fc.amount_in_currency * fer.GBP
    WHEN fc.currency = 'PLN' THEN fc.amount_in_currency
    END)
```

Optionally add a `WHERE` clause to restrict to a certain month and/or year.  Such as `WHERE fc.month = 2 AND fc.year_analysis = 2013`

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76b9566/1) using slightly modified data

For completeness, here are the tables that I would use to replace your current `fin_exchange_rates` table…

```
CREATE TABLE `fin_currencies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `abbreviation` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `displayCode` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

CREATE TABLE `fin_exchange_rates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateOfRate` date NOT NULL,
  `fromCurrencyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `toCurrencyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate` decimal(14,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `date_from_to` (`dateOfRate`,`fromCurrencyID`,`toCurrencyID`);
```

The solution would then become something like this…

```
UPDATE fin_costs fc
    JOIN fin_exchange_rates fer ON fc.year_analysis = YEAR(fer.dateOfRate)
        AND fc.month = MONTH(fer.dateOfRate)
    JOIN fin_currencies fcur1 ON fer.toCurrencyID = fcur1.id
      AND fcur1.abbreviation = fc.currency
    JOIN fin_currencies fcur2 ON fer.fromCurrencyID = fcur2.id
      AND fcur2.abbreviation = 'PLN'
SET fc.gross_amount = fc.amount_in_currency * fer.rate,
    fc.net_amount = fc.amount_in_currency * fer.rate
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29e8d/1) for the preferred solution.

Comment: At the moment I'm using the first option, and it works almost perfect, the only one issue actually is that for the PLN CASE is copying the value from the column amount_in_currency to the tables gross_amount and net_amount. (Have a look to SQLFiddle)

I deleted this line: 

 `code`WHEN fc.currency = 'PLN' THEN fc.amount_in_currency  `code`

but in this situation I get 0 as value for the gross_amount and net_amount.

Do you know how can I solve it?

Comment: @user2952715 In your original post, you don't show a rate for PLN, so I wasn't sure how you were treating it. I just assumed that PLN is the "base" currency and that it was not to be converted. If you actually have a `PLN` column in the `fin_exchange_rates` table, then use `WHEN fc.currency = 'PLN' THEN fc.amount_in_currency * fer.PLN`. If that's not the case, then you need to explain what you want done with it.

Comment: Thanks man, very elegant solution. I actually solved that problem using WHEN fc.currency = 'PLN' THEN name_of_the_column. Cheers!